# Pass data from parent component to child component using @input decorator in angular 8

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular-decorator

Hello i want to pass a number from component to another and i'm using @input.

Here my parent component :

```
@Component({

    selector: 'inter-asp',
    styleUrls: [('./asp.component.scss')],
    templateUrl: './asp.component.html',
    template: '<app-my-dialog [hellovariable]="hellovariable"></app-my-dialog>',
    providers: [PaginationConfig],
})

export class aspComponent implements OnInit {
    public hellovariable: number = 100;

}
```

and here my child component :

```
 @Component({
      selector: 'app-my-dialog',
      templateUrl: './my-dialog.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./my-dialog.component.css']
    })
    export class MyDialogComponent implements OnInit {

      @Input() hellovariable: number;
}
```

in the child component i want to show the content of my variable hellovariable passed from parent component but i get undefined it is not passed so what is the problem here.

Comment: @Sajeetharan-MSFT didn't understand u what mean print it

Comment: in your parent component you have templateUrl and template. You need remove one

Comment: @mecabmecab95 check on this link solve same problem i think its help you https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ezku8t

Comment: @Abhishek thank you now i did like ur exemple but  i have a problem in my parent component look for this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57820069/cant-bind-to-since-it-isnt-a-known-property-of-selector-component

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It takes preference to the template url, remove that part and have it as

```
@Component({
    selector: 'inter-asp',
    styleUrls: [('./asp.component.scss')],
    template: '<app-my-dialog [hellovariable]="hellovariable"></app-my-dialog>',
    providers: [PaginationConfig],
})
```

**[STACKBLITZ DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-input-kdffmv?file=app%2Fdialog%2FMyDialog.component.html)**

Comment: i did that but the variable still undefined in the child component

Comment: Check the demo above

Comment: when i put <app-my-dialog [hellovariable]="hellovariable"></app-my-dialog> in my parent component i get an error in chrome Can't bind to 'hellovariable' since it isn't a known property of 'app-my-dialog'

Comment: check the demo added

Comment: yes i did like the demo exactly but get the error in the chrome in my parent component template page html

Comment: which means you dont hav ethe variable in your ts file

Comment: i added it in the componet parent ts    public hellovariable: number = 100;

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199070/discussion-between-mecabmecab95-and-sajeetharan-msft).

Answer (score 0):

In the parent template you have to pass the input to the child as a property of the child component

```
<app-child-component [prop]="prop"></app-child-component>
```