# Can't bind to since it isn't a known property of selector component

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular8

I want to pass a variable from one component to another and I'm using @input

This is my parent component :

```
@Component({
    selector: 'aze',
    templateUrl: './aze.component.html',
    styleUrls: [('./aze.component.scss')],
    providers: [PaginationConfig],
})

export class azeComponent implements OnInit {
    public hellovariable: number = 100;
}
```

This is the template of the parent component:

```
<app-my-dialog [hellovariable]="hellovariable"></app-my-dialog>
```

This is my child component :

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-my-dialog',
  templateUrl: './my-dialog.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my-dialog.component.css']
})

export class MyDialogComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() hellovariable: number;
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(hellovariable);
  }
```

This is the child template:

```
 <h3>Hello I am {{hellovariable}}<h3>
```

And this is the app.module.ts:

```js
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        MyDialogComponent

    ],
    entryComponents: [
        MyDialogComponent
      ],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        routing,
        NgbModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        ToastrModule.forRoot(),
        RichTextEditorAllModule,
        FullCalendarModule,
        NgMultiSelectDropDownModule.forRoot(),
        LeafletModule.forRoot(),
        NgxGalleryModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        MatDialogModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule
    ],
```

When I show my parent component template I get this error:

> Can't bind to 'hellovariable' since it isn't a known property of 'app-my-dialog'.

Any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: Is the component added to the module?

Comment: you mean in the app.module.ts i have added parent component in declaration or no ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Few thing to try

First make sure you have import Input into your component

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
```

Then follow pascal convention when naming class

```
export class azeComponent implements OnInit
```

should change to

```
export class AzeComponent implements OnInit
```

Then register your component into your module `declarations`

Also import BrowserModule into your module also something like this

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    MyDialogComponent,
    AzeComponent   
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: I did all taht just when i have added the parent component to the declarations i will have another error Can't bind to 'dataSource' since it isn't a known property of 'table'

Comment: what library you are using

Comment: angular 8 and in the front angular material node 12.9.1

Comment: Then update your full code please. I cant help you if I cant see your code

Comment: i added my app.module.ts to question

Comment: Still confuse what is the error you have right now ?

Comment: Can't bind to 'hellovariable' since it isn't a known property of 'app-my-dialog'. in parent component html

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199071/discussion-between-mecabmecab95-and-tony-ngo).

Answer (score 1):

Mostly you'll get this error because you forgot to declare the component into your `app.module.ts` or did it wrong

### `app.module.ts`

```
import { YourSpecificComponent } from './components/measureUnit/measure-unit-monthly/measure-unit-monthly.component';

@NgModule({
declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    MessageComponent,
    DashboardComponent,
    .....,
    YourSpecificComponent, // declared here
}
```

### `your-specific.component.ts`

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-your-specific', // your selector
    templateUrl: './your-specific.component.html',
    styleUrls: [
        '../some.css'
    ]
})

export class YourSpecificComponent implements AfterContentInit {
.....
```

Answer (score -2):

ok this error causes because you need to import MyDialogComponent in azeComponent's module.